# Display N items that user has access to

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-data

Using Spring Data 1.4.2 and Sprint Security 3.1.4.RELEASE.

DAO:

```
public interface NewsDao extends 
    JpaRepository<News, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<News>{}
```

I want to get 5 newest news that user has access to:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject, 'VIEW')")
public List<News> findNewestGlobalNews() {
    Sort orderByDate = getSort();
    NewsDao newsDao = getDao();
    PageRequest newestOnly = new PageRequest(0, 5, orderByDate);
    List<News> news = newsDao.findAll(newestOnly).getContent();
    // because the list returned by Page is immutable and we do the filtering
    // according to ACL, return a copy of the list
    return new ArrayList<>(news);
}
```

This code works, but it suffers from obvious problem: we select 5 items from database and then filters out the ones that user has not access to. It causes that one user sees 3 news and another sees 4 although there are at least 5 news in the database that both users could possibly see.

I can think of selecting all items from database, then filtering them out and selecting the top 5, but I wonder if there is any more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The clean solution would be to directly query only the last 5 for a specific user. This obviously works only if you have this information in the database too.

If you have this access info only in the service layer you are left with either querying more if the list is smaller than 5 after the first query until you reach 5 in total.

Assuming that the query for news returns fast it will not mather that much to query 25 or X results instead so that the chance of not reaching the final 5 for a user is low enough and you live with the consequence of not reaching 5 in some cases :)